# IllegalStateException: It's not allowed to delete the file associated with an open Realm

Tags: java, android, realm, realm-migration

i've an exception when i call Realm.deleteRealm(config):

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: It's not allowed to delete the file
>   associated with an open Realm. Remember to close() all the instances
>   of the Realm before deleting its file

I call this just after Realm.init() in Application.onCreate, so there is no reason to have others instances opened.

```
public void onCreate() {
    Realm.init(this);

    Realm realm;
    RealmConfiguration config = getConfig();
    try {
        realm = Realm.getInstance(config); // Will migrate if needed
    } 
    catch (RealmMigrationNeededException e) 
    {
        Realm.deleteRealm(config);
        realm = Realm.getInstance(config);
    }
}
```

I saw theses topics but can't see the solution:

https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/4552

https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/5416

**Edit:**

I think my problem is when i restart application to try fail migration. In application i have instances opened but not closed, and can't close them easily, code is too much complex. And when i restart application to test migration exception with adding field to models, maybe there are some instances opened from previous launch.

**Edit 2:**

I tried to come back to realm 3.0.0 (my previous release), and i have not this IllegalStateException. I'm currently using 4.2.0.

Maybe i miss something in changelog..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before realm-java `4.1.0`, `Realm.deleteRealm()` is not a process-safe call. It means it doesn't throw if there are Realm instances opened in other processes. But deleting while Realm instances opened will have a big chance to corrupt the DB file.

From `4.1.0`, `Realm.deleteRealm()` is a multi-process safe API. It will throw if it detects there are Realm instances opened on other processes/threads.

So please check if you are using Realm in the other process and those are not closed properly before calling `deleteRealm()`.

Comment: Yes thx @beeender, you answered me on github, i forgot to close this stack.

https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/5570

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
public void onCreate() {
    Realm.init(this);

    Realm realm;
    RealmConfiguration config = getConfig();
    try {
        realm = Realm.getInstance(config); // Will migrate if needed
    } 
    catch (RealmMigrationNeededException e) 
    {
        realm.close();
        Realm.deleteRealm(config);
        realm = Realm.getInstance(config);
    }
}
```

instead of

```
public void onCreate() {
        Realm.init(this);

        Realm realm;
        RealmConfiguration config = getConfig();
        try {
            realm = Realm.getInstance(config); // Will migrate if needed
        } 
        catch (RealmMigrationNeededException e) 
        {
            Realm.deleteRealm(config);
            realm = Realm.getInstance(config);
        }
    }
```

Comment: No it's not working =(

I think my problem is when i restart application to try fail migration.
In application i have instances opened but not closed, and can't close them easily, code is too much complex. And when i restart application to test migration exception with adding field to models, maybe there are some instances opened from previous launch.

Comment: Can you try before open Realm ?
`RealmConfiguration rc = Realm.getDefaultConfiguration();

        if (rc != null) {
            Realm exRealm = Realm.getInstance(rc);
            exRealm.close();
        }
`

Comment: still not working, i'll try to come back to previous release to test, i think it was not crashing like that before

Comment: i tried to come back to realm 3.0.0 (my previous release), and i have not this IllegalStateException. I'm currently using 4.2.0.

Maybe i miss something in changelog..

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer from this topic:
https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/4552

If you know migration from version N to version N+1 throw this IllegalStateException, u can use DynamicRealm to check version and deleteRealm if needed.

More details in topic.

Answer (score 0):

add following line before deleting realm configuration.

```
realm.close();
```

Comment: Like dralexnumber solution, close in catch ? It was not working

Comment: @Lyofen i am using 3.7.0 version and it is working for me. try once with this version